# Куда делся Live Share в VS Code Linux(Manjaro)?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro

[image: Linux(Manjaro) исчез Live Share (VS Code)]

Ну что могу сказать, после нескольких дней использования, Live Share исчез.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего он не работает на Code OSS. Попробуйте скачать VSCode с [офсайта](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64). У меня на Xubuntu это расширение доступно.